# SQL joins error

Tags: php, sql, join

Can some please help explain/edit this code to identify why the doctor_id does not display. It is an SQL join from another table. The first SELECT statement to display appointment_date and appointment_time does work but the second SELECT statement, Doctor_id does not display the doctors information.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="my.js">
        </script>
        <!-- User-generated css -->
        <style>
        </style>
        <!-- User-generated js -->
        <script>
            try {

    $(function() {

    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Your javascript has an error: " + error);
  }
        </script>
     </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="d" href="login.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                    Back
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d"class="ui-btn-right">
                 Home  
                </a>
                <h3>
                    Book appointment
                </h3>
           </div>

           <div data-role="content">
                <h3>
                    Select date/time:
                </h3>
                <br />
     <?php
{
    mysql_connect("localhost" , "" , "") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());


    $pid=intval($_SESSION["Patient_id"]); $query = "SELECT Appointment_id, Doctor_id, Patient_id, Appointment_time, Appointment_date FROM Appointment where Patient_id=$pid";
    SELECT * Doctor_id
    FROM Appointment
    JOIN Doctor
    ON Appointment.Doctor_id=Doctor.Doctor_id

    //executes query on the database
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");
    //this selects the results as rows

    $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);
    //if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
    if ($num == 1) {}
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['Appointment_date'] = $row['Appointment_date'];
        $_SESSION['Appointment_time'] = $row['Appointment_time'];
        $_SESSION['Doctor_id'] = $row['Doctor_id'];

    }
}
?>  

        <strong>Dates available</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Select date--</option>
        <option value="1"><?php echo $_SESSION['Appointment_date'];?></option>
        </select>

        <br />
        <br />

        <strong>Times available</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Select time--</option>
        <option value="2"><?php echo $_SESSION['Appointment_time'];?></option>>
        </select>

        <strong>Times available</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Select time--</option>
        <option value="2"><?php echo $_SESSION['Doctor_id'];?></option>>
        </select>

        <br />
        <br />

                <label for="textarea1">
                Message GP
                </label>
                <textarea name="" id="textarea1" placeholder="">
                </textarea>


             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: The second SELECT isn't in a string, it isn't assigned to a variable. Your PHP file should be reporting a syntax error.

Comment: @j0k Thank you, i will look at the tutorial

Comment: @Barmar, i am new to this. What would i need to do?

Comment: You need to do something similar to the first SELECT: `$query2 = "SELECT ...";` and then call `mysql_query($query2);`. Also, when you call die it should be `die ("didn't query: ". mysql_error());` so you see the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make tables easier to write, add an alias on them,

```
SELECT a.*, b.Doctor_id
FROM   Appointment a
       INNER JOIN Doctor b
          ON a.Doctor_id = b.Doctor_id
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thank you. Is this the reason why it is not working or is this just to improve the structure?

Comment: your statement only queries on the `Appointment` table. and the `JOIN` statement isn't stored on the variable which you need to execute it. do the join just like what you did in your `$query` var.